Add multiple entries in XML File
I have a form containing a TextBox and a RichTextBox. The RichTextBox contains text to be edited by the user and the TextBox contains the descriptive name for the text. I want to save the RichTextBox text with the name describing it in an XML File.   I am using the following code to do this.
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Dim doc As XDocument = Nothing
    Dim RTBText As String = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim TextBoxText As String = TextBox1.Text
    createNode(TextBoxText, RTBText, doc)
    doc.Save(filename)
End Sub

Private Sub createNode(ByVal varname As String, ByVal varvalue As String, ByRef doc As XDocument)
    Dim identification As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?><Log></Log>"
    doc = XDocument.Parse(identification)
    Dim EntryData As XElement = doc.FirstNode
    Dim EntryDate = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyy")
    Dim variables As New XElement("Entry", New Object() {
                                  New XElement("EntryDescription", varname),
                                  New XElement("EntryValue", varvalue),
                                  New XElement("EntryDate", EntryDate)
                                  })
    EntryData.Add(variables)

End Sub

The code produces the following XML File.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Log>
  <Entry>
    <EntryDescription>This is the TextTextbox Text</EntryDescription>
    <EntryValue>This is RTB Data</EntryValue>
    <EntryDate>181024</EntryDate>
  </Entry>
</Log>

The file will not have more than a few hundred entries and this seems to be fine but I can't find out how to add additional entries to the file.  As it is, the next entry just overwrites the existing entry.  When complete, I need to be able to search the XML file's descriptive names and then retrieve the accompanying text.   Please could someone assist in finding a solution that will enable me to add additional entries.

It isn't clear to me where the code first reads in the existing file so that the new entries can be added.

I prefer to use XElement and LINQ,
Public Class Form1

    Private doc As XElement = Nothing
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filename As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        filename = IO.Path.Combine(filename, "FOOtest.xml")
        If doc Is Nothing Then
            If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                doc = XElement.Load(filename) 'open file if exists
            Else
                doc = <log></log> 'create new
                doc.Save(filename)
            End If
        End If
        createNode(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text) 'add node
        doc.Save(filename) 'and save
    End Sub

    Private Sub createNode(varname As String,
                            varvalue As String)
        Dim EntryDate As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy")
        Dim variables As XElement
        'build a new entry
        variables = <Entry>
                        <EntryDescription><%= varname %></EntryDescription>
                        <EntryValue><%= varvalue %></EntryValue>
                        <EntryDate><%= EntryDate %></EntryDate>
                    </Entry>
        doc.Add(variables) 'add to existing
    End Sub
End Class

edit - another approach
Public Class Form1

    Private doc As XElement = Nothing
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filename As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        filename = IO.Path.Combine(filename, "FOOtest.xml")
        If doc Is Nothing Then
            If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                doc = XElement.Load(filename) 'open file if exists
            Else
                doc = <log></log> 'create new
                doc.Save(filename)
            End If
        End If
        doc.Add(createEntryNode(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text)) 'add node
        doc.Save(filename) 'and save
    End Sub

    Private Function createEntryNode(varname As String,
                                      varvalue As String) As XElement
        Dim EntryDate As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy")
        Dim variables As XElement
        'build a new entry
        variables = <Entry>
                        <EntryDescription><%= varname %></EntryDescription>
                        <EntryValue><%= varvalue %></EntryValue>
                        <EntryDate><%= EntryDate %></EntryDate>
                    </Entry>
        Return variables
    End Function
End Class


I'm sure there must be other methods for different requirements, but in my case, this was perfect.  Thank you

Using XmlSerialization,
Define a model for your data. You can pass around log entry objects, or even logs.
<XmlRoot>
Partial Public Class Log
    <XmlElement("Entry")>
    Public Property Entries As List(Of LogEntry)
    Public Sub New()
        Entries = New List(Of LogEntry)()
    End Sub
End Class
Partial Public Class LogEntry
    Public Property EntryDescription As String
    Public Property EntryValue As String
    Public Property EntryDate As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(entryDescription As String, entryValue As String, entryDate As String)
        Me.EntryDescription = entryDescription
        Me.EntryValue = entryValue
        Me.EntryDate = entryDate
    End Sub
End Class

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Private xmlPath As String = "Test.xml"

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await AddToLogAsync(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text, Date.Today.ToString("ddMMyy"))
End Sub

Private Sub AddToLog(entryDescription As String, entryValue As String, entryDate As String)
    Dim log As Log
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Log))
    If File.Exists(xmlPath) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(xmlPath)
            log = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Log)
        End Using
    Else
        log = New Log()
    End If
    log.Entries.Add(New LogEntry(entryDescription, entryValue, entryDate))
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(xmlPath)
        serializer.Serialize(sw, log)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function AddToLogAsync(entryDescription As String, entryValue As String, entryDate As String) As Task
    Return Task.Run(New Action(Sub() AddToLog(entryDescription, entryValue, entryDate)))
End Function

You can call the synchronous version
AddToLog(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text, Date.Today.ToString("ddMMyy"))

But that will run on your UI (like you are doing now). The asynchronous version will not freeze your UI while reading and writing.
